# whitelist_from_rcvd in Spamassassin not working - not whitelisting

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I want to use `whitelist_from_rcvd` and exclude my own email addresses at the same time avoiding for them to be forgered by spammers.

But it seems that it's not working and my own messages are still being scanned by spamassassin, assigned a score and their subjects gets rewritten.

The test email below is sent from a contact form on the website hosted on 94.177.253.49. The postserver is at 185.43.211.43.

Here is the header of a test email:

```
Return-Path: <xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on mail01
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: **************************************************
X-Spam-Report:
        * -1.0 ALL_TRUSTED Passed through trusted hosts only via SMTP
        *  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
        *       See http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
        *      for more information.
        *      [URIs: sdfasfa.com]
        *  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
        *      valid
        * 1000 GTUBE BODY: Generic Test for Unsolicited Bulk Email
        *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
        *  1.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
        *  0.6 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag
        *  0.1 DKIM_INVALID DKIM or DK signature exists, but is not valid
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=1000.9 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_INVALID,
        DKIM_SIGNED,GTUBE,HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,
        URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
Delivered-To: spammail@glmr.in
Received: by mail.glmr.in (Postfix, from userid 994)
        id 9864F1373; Wed,  3 Oct 2018 14:59:07 +0200 (CEST)
X-Sieve: Pigeonhole Sieve 0.4.2
X-Sieve-Redirected-From: xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net
Delivered-To: xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net
Received: from www.tantramassageamsterdam.net (unknown [94.177.253.49])
        (Authenticated sender: xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net)
        by mail.glmr.in (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id E462A428
        for <xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net>; Wed,  3 Oct 2018 14:59:01 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
        d=tantramassageamsterdam.net; s=default; t=1538571541;
        bh=mc/T6m7UlKFYERygzKcKT3rp91BfuBS+NZA/4Q+RdIA=;
        h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject;
        b=gIZXOKkFKjZRSm9gO0sv6qInvC/vt+jOlBapSlKNhet4u6KScpPqM+FY4mRumYoKG
         YhAK8xMd8vDu+LkVhG5BIZRh+ZUb2QFOkSERpsIK+kUHwk2wfjd09OFK13gmzp6ZE8
         VPLTJRxAtMVE0m+m0wOENytzJdebwI5sk6wRH0OA=
Date: Wed, 3 Oct 2018 12:59:01 +0000
To: xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net
From: Tantra Massage Amsterdam <xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net>
Reply-To: test <test@sdfasfa.com>
Subject: [SPAM] New booking information
Message-ID: <64742fafbb05a2f31dbc4c8f63707166@www.tantramassageamsterdam.net>
X-Mailer: WPMailSMTP/Mailer/smtp 1.3.3
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Spam-Prev-Subject: New booking information
X-Spam-Prev-Subject: [SPAM] New booking information
```

Here is the local.cf

```
required_hits 5
report_safe 0
rewrite_header Subject [SPAM]

add_header all Status _YESNO_, score=_SCORE_ required=_REQD_ tests=_TESTS_ autolearn=_AUTOLEARN_ version=_VERSION_

trusted_networks 185.43.211.43
trusted_networks 94.177.253.49
trusted_networks 80.211.255.82
trusted_networks 80.211.183.70

whitelist_from_rcvd hello@tantramassageamsterdam.net www.tantramassageamsterdam.net
whitelist_from_rcvd hello@tantramassageamsterdam.net tantramassageamsterdam.net
```

Here is part the output of `spamassassin -D -L -t`:
https://pastebin.com/zuU1mKt1
(it's too long to paste here)

Please help to properly use `whitelist_from_rcvd` so that I whitelist my email addresses with the emails really sent from the websites I manage.

Answer (score 0):

Your test email was received from www.tantramassageamsterdam.net, not from tantramassageamsterdam.net. Try to change second whitelist_from_rcvd to

```
whitelist_from_rcvd xxx@tantramassageamsterdam.net www.tantramassageamsterdam.net
```

P.S. And add `trusted_networks` to your local.cf for better processing of Received headers.

Comment: With the www. still not working. I also added the trusted networks, one line with the IP addresses of all the server, post server, and websites where the contact forms are hosted. Restarted the service. It's still marking the mails as spam :/

Comment: Can you update test email headers, local.cf and spamassassin -D output in your question after your configuration modification?

Comment: please find the updates you requested

Comment: 1. You should use only one `trusted_networks` line in local.cf. You can list several IP in it separated by spaces: `trusted_networks 185.43.211.43 94.177.253.49 80.211.255.82 80.211.183.70`

Comment: 2. whitelist_from_rcvd does not work because Spamassassin can't detect from `Received:` headers that the message was received from www.tantramassageamsterdam.net. The problematic header is `Received: from www.tantramassageamsterdam.net (unknown [94.177.253.49])`. It should be `Received: from www.tantramassageamsterdam.net (www.tantramassageamsterdam.net [94.177.253.49])` but Postfix at mail.glmr.in can't resolve 94.177.253.49 to `www.tantramassageamsterdam.net` and writes `unknown` instead.

Comment: As a result Spamassassin does not detect that the message was received from www.tantramassageamsterdam.net and whitelist_from_rcvd rule does not match. You should add rDNS record for 94.177.253.49 pointing to www.tantramassageamsterdam.net. It is a good rule to have rDNS records for all hosts sending email messages.

Comment: I put all in one line. Restarted the service, but the problem is still there It marks the messages sent via contact form as spam. 94.177.253.49 is a webserver with many websites. It already has one rDNS name configured. The problem is that there can be only 1 rDNS per IP. So... if that would fix for this website, what about the rest? I don't think this is a solution :/
P.s. don't type/paste here the domain name of the rDNS of IP 94.177.253.49 - it contains a personal name... just for privacy reasons and avoiding google to crawl and index it

Comment: It is ok if rDNS points not to `www.tantramassageamsterdam.net`, but to some other name, `mail.example.com` for example. My host does resolve 94.177.253.49 to correct domain name. But for some reason Postfix at mail.glmr.in can't resolve 94.177.253.49 to s..o.com domain name and writes `unknown` to Received headers instead of s..o.com. I think that it is the reason of whitelisting not working. Do you control mail.glmr.in server? Can you run `host 94.177.253.49` and check the output?

Comment: Yes, I control it.
`[root@mail01 ~]# host 94.177.253.49
49.253.177.94.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer s*****.com` - maybe there is sth wrong with postfix. The server from SSH seems to resolve well. Also nslookup resolves to IP and to rDNS

Comment: You can try to send another message from tantramassageamsterdam.net and check postfix logs, maybe there will be some clue there. You can add diagnostic messages from postfix logs here but maybe this problem deserves separate question at Server Fault. I am sure that spamassassin problem caused by `www.tantramassageamsterdam.net (unknown [94.177.253.49])` - I saved your message to local file, replaced `unknown` with `www.tantramassageamsterdam.net` and my local spamassassin matched the message with your whitelist_from_rcvd rule.

Comment: yeah, but strange, that `trusted_networks` is not whitelisting it either.

Comment: `trusted_networks` does not mean that all messages from these networks are not spam. It is used only to tell spamassassin that you are sure that these hosts SMTP servers are not controlled by spammers and it can trust Received headers created by these hosts. [https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/TrustPath]